# Inserir sqlite em aplicação android

Tags: android, sqlite

Estou desenvolvendo um banco de dados em sqlite a parte da aplicação. Neste momento estou usando o SqliteBrowser, e gostaria de saber como fazer para pegar o banco de dados e colocar para a aplicação ler este. Tenho uma leve noção que tenho que criar uma classe a parte para o database mas é somente isso que sei.

Answer (score 2):

Você deve criar uma classe que estenda de `SQLiteOpenHelper`, onde ela vai ser responsável em criar seu banco de dados no dispositivo baseado nas instruções SQL fornecidas por você.

Exemplo:

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper   {


    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "NOME_DO_ARQUIVO_DO_BANCO.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static DBHelper instance;

    private static SQLiteDatabase com;

    private Context context;
    public DBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        this.context = context;
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {


        database.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TABELA1 (ID INTEGER, nome varchar(100) PRIMARY KEY ([ID]));");
        database.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TABELA2 (ID INTEGER, nome varchar(100) PRIMARY KEY ([ID]));");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase database, int versaoAntiga, int novaVersao) {


    }


    public static DBHelper getInstance(Context context){        
        if (instance == null){
            instance = new DBHelper(context);
        }   
        return instance;    


    }

    //cria a conexao com o banco de dados
    public SQLiteDatabase open() throws SQLException {

        if (com == null){
            com = this.getWritableDatabase();
            if (!com.isReadOnly()) {
                // Enable foreign key constraints
                com.execSQL("PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON;");
            }

        }
        return com;
    }




}
```

E para acessar seu banco de dados basta fazer o seguinte:

private DBHelper dbHelper;
private SQLiteDatabase connection;

```
dbHelper = DBHelper.getInstance(context);               
connection = dbHelper.open();
```

Salvando um registro no banco:

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put("ID",1);
values.put("NOME","JOÃO");
connection.insertOrThrow("TABELA1", null,values);
```

Answer (score 1):

A primeira coisa a se fazer é copiar o seu arquivo **"meubanco.db"** para a pasta da aplicação android. Para isso, faça o seguinte:

1. Crie uma pasta chamada **assets** em: *CaminhoDoProjeto/app/src/main*
2. Copie o arquivo **"meubanco.db"** para a pasta **assets**

Em seguida, você deve criar uma classe que irá fazer a abertura,leitura, fechamento, etc. do banco de dados. Essa classe deve extender `SQLiteOpenHelper`. Um exemplo seria:

```
public class Database extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/pacote.da.aplicaco/databases/";
private static String DB_NAME = "meubanco.db";
private SQLiteDatabase bdQuery;
private final Context bdContext;

public Database(Context context) {

    super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
    this.bdContext = context;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    // Utilize este método para criar o banco de dados direto da aplicação
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // Atualiza o banco de dados se houver uma versão nova.

}

private void criarBancoDeDados() throws IOException {

    boolean dbExist = checarBancoDeDados();

    if (!dbExist) {
        this.getReadableDatabase();

        try {
            this.copiarBancoDeDados();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new Error("Erro ao copiar o Banco de Dados!");
        }
    }
}

private void copiarBancoDeDados() throws IOException {

    InputStream myInput = bdContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
    String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }

    myOutput.flush();
    myOutput.close();
    myInput.close();

}

private boolean checarBancoDeDados() {

    SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

    String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

    if (checkDB != null) {
        checkDB.close();
    }

    return checkDB != null ? true : false;
}

private void abrirBancoDeDados() throws SQLException {

    String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    bdQuery = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,
            SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);

    //Permite que a aplicação reconheça chaves estrangeiras
    bdQuery.execSQL("PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;");

}

public void setBancoDados() {

    try {
        criarBancoDeDados();
        abrirBancoDeDados();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
}
```

Neste caso, quando você quisesse "criar" o banco de dados, você precisaria fazer:

```
Database mDatabase = new Database(mContext);
mDatabase.setBancoDeDados();
```