# Como adicionar vários números no Sharedpreferences e manter sempre a instancia do SharedPreferences?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

Eu precisava adicionar um dado no Sharedpreferences e ele irarmazenanando todos os dados, não "zerar" mais meus dados. Estou usando o `editor.putStringSet("data", dado);` para armazenar meus dados, eu precisava manter esses dados para sempre. É possível fazer isso? Agradeço desde já!

Comment: Sharedpreferences serve para isso mesmo, persistir dados. É claro que ao desinstalar a aplicação eles são perdidos.

Comment: Sim, o SharedPreferences salva tudo em um xml que você só perde se desinstalar, o problema é que quando eu crio SharedPreferences eu estou criando uma nova lista e colocando novos dados, eu precisava manter os dados, vou tentar criaro SharedPreferences no onSaveInstanceState para ver se da certo.

Comment: Não sei se entendi o seu problema mas sempre que `put` é usado, para uma determinada chave, o valor anterior é substituído.

Comment: exatamente, porque eu recrio o sharedPreferences, eu precisava manter ele, e toda vez que eu salvar a minha activity, salvar meus dados, mantendo os dados anteriores.

Comment: Isso só é possível se você mudar a chave: 1ª vez - `editor.putStringSet("data1", dado);` 2ª vez - `editor.putStringSet("data2", dado);` etc. Mas isso é complicado de gerir, o melhor seria usar uma DB.

Comment: Explique melhor o que pretende fazer.

Comment: é verdade, tem este problema da chave mesmo. Eu precisava armazenar todos os textos de uma ListView que eu clicasse em um StringSet. Quando eu clico em um item do ListView eu mudo a cor do item, daí eu precisava destes dados para quando criar a activity usar esses dados para colocar a cor nos itens que foram clicados. Neste caso o onSaveInstanceState não funcionaria, quero evitar de usar BD, o SharedPreferences parecia uma boa opção.

Comment: Se eu entendi bem o que você quer é guardar o estado(clicados/não clicados) dos itens da lista para que ao abrir de novo a *activity* esse estado seja reposto. Se é isto, *SharedPreferences* é uma boa opção. Coloque o código que já fez para eu poder dar uma resposta.

Comment: vlw pela ajuda Ramaral, mas vou salvar isto em um banco mesmo, acho que vai ficar até mais fácil para manipular os dados.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para manter os dados antigos você deve inserir uma nova chave.
Aqui um exemplo de gerar uma chave baseado no GUID, onde esta chave nunca se repetirá.

Importe: `import java.util.UUID;`

e Faça o seguinte:

```
UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID();
String randomUUIDString = uuid.toString();
editor.putStringSet(randomUUIDString , dado);
```

Espero ter ajudado.

Mas eu recomendo você criar um banco de dados  `SQLITE`, assim você terá um controle sobre suas informações podendo fazer buscas e alterar os dados de forma fácil e rápida.

Veja minha resposta nesta pergunta  [Inserir sqlite em aplicação android](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/81525/inserir-sqlite-em-aplica%C3%A7%C3%A3o-android/86802#86802) . Isso vai com certeza te ajudar a implementar um banco `SQLITE` no android.

Comment: Como é que isto pode ser funcional? Você utiliza um *randomUUID* para as chaves. Como é então possível recuperar um determinado valor se não sabemos qual foi a chave usada para o guardar?.

Comment: Por isso recomendei a você usar um banco http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/81525/inserir-sqlite-em-aplica%C3%A7%C3%A3o-android/86802#86802 Qualquer duvida estou a disposição para ajuda-lo.